# Faster way to solve $\cot\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \cdot \cot\left(2x + \frac{\pi}{4}\right) = -1$ in $[-2\pi, 2\pi]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I want to know if there is a faster way to solve $\cot\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \cdot \cot\left(2x + \frac{\pi}{4}\right) = -1$ in $[-2\pi,2\pi]$.

I solved it by "brute force", expressing everything as $\sin(x),\cos(x)$ and its powers, getting that the equation is equivalent to $\sin(x)+\cos(x) = 0$ after simplyfing, but it is a little bit tedious. Is there any other way to solve this equation that does not require that amount of algebra? This exercise is given to students and they have to solve it fast, so thats why I think a faster way exists.

Answer (score 3):

$\cot(\frac \pi2 - x) = \tan x\\
\cot(x-\frac \pi2) = -\tan x$

$-\tan x\cot (2x + \frac \pi 4) = -1\\
\tan x = \tan (2x + \frac \pi 4)\\
x = 2x + \frac {\pi}{4} + n\pi\\
x = -\frac {\pi}{4} + n\pi$